# Atom node debugger as good as the one at visual studio code

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, atom-editor

I know there is a similar question here ([Debugging nodejs with atom IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36920768/debugging-nodejs-with-atom-ide)) but it is not exactly what I'm asking.

I'm currently using atom for node programming and visual studio code for debugging. This is very uncomfortable and inefficient. The reason? The node debugger of visual studio code is amazing, very useful and easy to use. I was wondering if it is an equivalent for atom. I tried already node-debugger and it is a very poor alternative to visual studio code. Is there any good package for node debugging in atom?

If not, could someone suggest an editor that has the best of both, VSC and atom? The only things that are keeping me away from visual studio code are the totally useless fixed left bar, the lack of a symbols explorer and a visual branch manager (maybe also a minimap).

Comment: For what it's worth, they added tabs in the latest version.

Comment: @JoeClay, I just saw it. One more point for VSC. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean with "fixed left bar"?

Comment: Hello @BenjaminPasero, I mean the left bar where you can switch from editing, to debugging to git management and so on.

Comment: We call this the activity bar and it provides functionality to show indicators on each of those areas as well as provides easy access to switch.

Comment: Sorry @BenjaminPasero, when I said useless I mean useless to me most of the time. Of course I do use it, but ti takes a precious screen space that sometimes I wish I had available.

Comment: @Danielo515 You can hide/toggle most of it by clicking on the already active activity.

Comment: @SteveMoser, when I said that it was not possible to hide the sidebar. Now VsCode is my editor of choice. Regards